Oracle SQL Developer change preferences location
I'm running on Oracle SQL Developer (hereinafter, OSD) 23.1.
I need to distribute a homogeneous installation of OSD across multiple Citrix instances, children of a golden image, and, refering to configuration, I need to stablish the content of
Tools --> Preferences --> Database --> Advanced, so it looks like this:

Yet, after some reverse engineering, I found those properties in the image are persisted at
%appdata%\SQL Developer\system23.1.0.097.1607\o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml
and %appdata%\SQL Developer is not created in the user profile until user runs for the first time OSD.
So the question is:
How can I configure OSD_23.1, so that that configuration relays in system, persisted-files, and not in the user's data (%appdata%)?
Thanks so much!

A possible solution is to update the SQLDeveloper preferences file as needed before starting the program.
That file is located in %appData%/Roaming\SQL Developer\system<version_number>\o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml
The section that includes this configuration is:
<hash n="OracleHomeSettings">
<hash n="HomeRoot">
<hash n="OracleClient">
<url n="HomeLocation" path="../../../../../../../software/oracle/product/19.0.0/"/>
<value n="HomeType" v="FULL_HOME"/>
</hash>
<value n="UseClient" v="true"/>
</hash>
</hash>

In the following link, you can find a PowerShell code that you can reuse if you decide to follow this approach:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Software/Oracle-SQL-Developer/directories/user-information/systemV_W_X_Y_Z/o_sqldeveloper/product-preferences_xml/index
